# cart_total_amount showing 0 in django-shopping-cart

Tags: python, django, django-templates, e-commerce, django-shop

I have added
cart.context_processor.cart_total_amount in settings.py
But when i use it in the template it shows 0

I was expecting the total cart amount so want to know why the total cart amount is not showing up in {{cart_total_amount}}

Comment: Please share a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: in have used it like... <td>Subtotal</td>  <td>{{cart_total_amount}} </td>

Comment: We don't know what you have written in your code and why is the code not working as expected, so please share the necessary code, and the things you have tried to fix it.